# Update a child in realtime database? How?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

[image: db structure]

running a query and saving the data in below form in realtime db. Every time query runs it creates a new node but what i want is no need to create a new node for already existing emails just update the points like (emailid1, points of emailid2 etc). and if the emailid is not in the list then create a new email id.

Comment: It's a good idea to include what platform you are using and also some sample code to show where the issue is. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `update()` method. The documentation is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update).

> As opposed to the `set()` method, `update()` can be use to selectively
>   update only the referenced properties at the current location (instead
>   of replacing all the child properties at the current location).

You could for example write a function like:

```
function updatePoints(itemId, newPoints) {

  //itemId = id of the node you want to update, e.g. -LEU3DUphg...
  //newPoints = the new points value

  var updates = {};
  updates['/.../' + itemId + '/points'] = newPoints; 

  return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
}
```